# how to make svelte stores reactive across different components

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using svelte store for reactivity, but and I have problem with my components not updating when the the store state changes.

the store code looks like the following

```
import { writable, type Writable } from "svelte/store";
import { browser } from "$app/environment";

export interface Widget {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  youtube: boolean;
  twitch: boolean;
  };
}

let data: Widget[] = [];
if (browser) {
  data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("widgets") || "[]");
}

export const widget: Writable<Widget[]> = writable(data);

if (browser) {
  widget.subscribe((data) => {
    localStorage.setItem("widgets", JSON.stringify(data));
  });
}
```

It works as expected, but I can't update the store state in one component and have the other components update automatically, I have to reload the page manually to see the changes happen.

this is what I'm using to update store state

```
<script lang="ts">
// imports...

  export let widget: Widget

  function update() {
    widgetstore.update((wid) => {
      const index = wid.findIndex((w) => w.id === widget.id);
      wid[index] = widget;
      return wd;
    });
  }

</script>

<form on:change={update}>
  <div>
    <input bind:checked={widget.youtube} type="checkbox" name="youtube" />
    <label for="youtube">YouTube</label>
  </div>
  <div >
    <input bind:checked={widget.twitch} type="checkbox" name="twitch" />
    <label for="twitch">Twitch</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is the component that does not react to the updates, which exist on a different route

```
<script lang="ts">
// imports...

let index = $widgetstore.findIndex((el) => el.id === id)
$: yt = $widgetstore[index].youtube;
$: tw = $widgetstore[index].twitch;
</script>

<Comp>YouTube {yt ? "Disconnected" : "Connected"}</Comp>
<Comp>Twitch {yt ? "Disconnected" : "Connected"}</Comp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let index` is not reactive, so that might have the wrong value on page load.

Try making it reactive as well.

Also, in the `update` call is a `return wd`, `wd` is not defined, if that is your actual code that should be `wid`. Would recommend not using such useless abbreviations, prevents errors.

There should be no issue with the store itself.

If the store should update on another page, you need to listen to the [`storage` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) (it only fires on other pages) and reload the value from storage.

Comment: I did, but that's not what causing it.

Comment: Added another note about your store update. You should check the running code to observe the various values in a debugger and if there are console errors add those to the question.

Comment: Could it be because I'm using a different route for the component that is supposed to be reactive when I update the store?

Comment: If you are talking about having *different pages* open (in tabs/windows) and expecting the other to update, that does not work. You would have to listen to the `storage` event and reload the value from the storage.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, thank you 

Comment: Updated the answer with that. You could accept the answer with the checkmark.